# Does slicing create a new unique object or not? Two seemingly conflicting examples with lists

Tags: python, slice, python-3.7

I'm going through a book on Python and they initially introduced list slicing as a way to create a complete copy of a list, not just a reference. However, later in the book an example is given where they alter a list slice and the previously instantiated list is also altered, the kind of behavior you would expect if only a reference was copied.

I'll include two simple examples of each things below.

I've double checked whether or not slicing returns a new copied list with a different id and everything i found said it did return a unique list, not just a reference.

---

First snippet of code was introduced in the book as a way of copying the contents of a list into a new list.

```
exList = ['0', '1', '2', '3']

exCopy = exList[:]
```

I am currently understanding this as the slice operator returns a new list with the contents of `exList`, which is then assigned to `exCopy`.

---

This next snippet of code alters the content of a list slice, which proves to alter the full list as well. With my previous understanding, I thought that changes to the sliced list would not alter the list itself because the slice would represent its own unique list copy (again not a reference, but list copy).

```
aliens = []

for alien_Number in range(30):
    new_alien = {'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}
    aliens.append(new_alien)


for alien in aliens[:3]:
    if alien['color'] == 'green':
        alien['color'] = 'yellow'

for alien in aliens[:5]:
    print(alien)
print("...")
```

Comment: *This next snippet of code alters the content of a list slice* - can you point to the piece of code which you think does that?

Comment: I'd imagine that the line `alien['color'] = 'yellow'` does that...

Comment: The list of aliens contains dicts, which are passed by reference.  So when you slice your list, you're making a copy of the list, each copy containing references to the same dicts.  You're not altering the content of the list, you're altering the contents of the dicts.

Comment: Is this another iteration of the shallow vs deep copy question?

Comment: @mikewatt no, **nothing is ever passed by reference in Python**. Certainly, the *type* of object has no bearing. Simply put, whenever you shallow copy, which is what a slice does, the same objects will populate the new `list`. In any case, "pass by reference" would only be relevant to function calls, because it refers to an evaluation strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Slicing creates a copy. Easy to test example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a[:]
b[1] = 5
print('b',b)
print('a',a)
```

The result is:

```
b [1, 5, 3]
a [1, 2, 3]
```